# Display errors on Laravel live website

Tags: laravel, forge, laravel-forge

My Laravel project is all set up on Laravel Forge using Github and Linode. Since the site has been live, I can no longer see the errors displaying when I am developing. On the localhost, all the errors displayed and I knew why I was having problems.

Is anyone familiar with Laravel Forge and know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in forge the environment is setup as production, forge also setup the

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

you need to change that to `APP_DEBUG=true`

you do that by clicking on the environment button in Laravel forge and modifying the values

if you want to view errors now thats generally not recommended for security reasons and a whole lot more. you can find packages that will log your issues or even monitor issue through exception catching.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, and I got problem sorted out.

Comment: awesome @AlexNaughton

Answer (score 0):

It is all written in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#environment-configuration).

> Forge sets up environment as "production", log in using SSH and change .env file to whatever you desire. Same with migrations it asks you to "do you really want to run migrations?"

If you don't know how to edit file using terminal, you may try this [package](https://github.com/svenluijten/flex-env) which allows you to change `.env` file via artisan.

Or try using vim (sudo only if you log to the machine as different user as forge):

```
$ sudo vim .env
```

Now press `i` *(insert mode)* use arrows to move cursor and change whatever you need, when you are done press `esc` *(normal mode)* and type `:wq`.